# FB.XFBML.parse function is not working in angular2 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have configured facebook comments by following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) link.
It works fine normally and in angular2 application.

I have configured several router in my angular2 app.
Only one of the router is configured to load facebook comments. When i load that router for the first time, it works fine; but if i switched to some other router/link and comes back, it does not show up.

Below is my facebookCommentAPI code which i modified to suit into angular way.

```
declare let FB : any;
@Component({
  selector: 'facebookComment',
  template: `
    <div id="{{fbCommentID}}">
      <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/SenapatiJyotirmay/" data-width="900" data-numposts="3">
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class FacebookCommentComponent {

  protected js;
  protected fjs;
  protected childNode;
  public fbCommentID : any;
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private _zone: NgZone, protected router : Router, public r : Renderer, public el : ElementRef) {

    this.fbCommentID = "fbCommentId";
    this.loadFBCommentAPI(this.document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
  }

  loadFBCommentAPI = (d, s, id) => {
    this._zone.run(() => {
      this.js, this.fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

      if (typeof FB === 'object') {
        console.log("coming");
        FB.XFBML.parse(); 
        return;
      }
      this.js = d.createElement(s); 
      this.js.id = id;
      this.js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=1834265296843281";
      this.childNode = this.fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(this.js, this.fjs);
     });
  }

}
```

**Index.html**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

No facebook SDK script added. It loads asynchronously from component when we call loadFBCommentAPI function.

There is no error in console and  does not hold DOM elements which it does when loaded for the first time.

I am not able to run FB.XFBML.parse() from angular component. It works when manually ran from browser developer console.

---

Comment: Hey @CBroe, in angular2 it says "FB is not defined". Any help please.

Comment: Perhaps a scope issue. You should really not implement loading of the SDK all over the place (it won't load the script itself repeatedly anyway), but initialize it once when your app loads.

Comment: But, i won't understand why it is not loading from second time onwards??

Comment: Because the code snippet is _designed_ to load the SDK only once. And it goes through your document only once on initialization, to look for elements to convert into social plugins. If you add such elements later on, you need to instruct the SDK to re-parse the document - and that is what FB.XFBML.parse is for.

Comment: Nice. This works fine if i run FB.XFBML.parse() from browser developer console, but not able to run it from angular.

Comment: Have you embedded and initialized the SDK before calling it ...?

Comment: First time it is loading SDK to browser. From next time onwards i am checking if "FB" is an object then proceeding to call FB.XFBML.parse() but it does not do anything. At the same time if i will run it from browser it works. I updated my issue and code after hell lot of experiment, but still no solution and exhausted. :(

Comment: I believe in angular2 `declare let FB : any;` this is the way to embed and initialise.